# How can I count unique records from a column in my MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding an analytics script for my website that tracks traffic sources. When a user visits a page the following info gets recorded in my database: page, referrer, date, ip. I want to list the different referrers in a table along with the number of times that unique referrer shows up in the column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select referrer, count(*) as NumberOfHits
from yourTable
group by referrer`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT referrer, COUNT(referrer) FROM table_name GROUP BY referrer;
```